# How do I convert a bitstring to an utf-8 string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, utf-8, bitstring

I use the [bitstring](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/index.html) module. What is the easiest way to convert a bitstring to an utf-8 string?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @user2387370: I use python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.bytes` property on a `BitVector` to convert the sequence of bits in the vector into the same sequence of bits in the form of a Python (2.7) `str` object.

Because `str`s are encoding-agnostic, you could consider yourself done at this point, provided that the sequence of bits that you stored in your vector correspond to a UTF-8--encoded Unicode string. (In other words, using this approach it's up to you to store bits in your vector that correspond to some UTF-8--encoded sequence of Unicode characters.)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in bitstring module documentation:

```
# To covert to an ordinary string use the bytes property
open('video.m2v', 'wb').write(s.bytes)
```

Information available [here](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/examples.html).